# Enforcing ppolicy to openldap users

Tags: apache, openldap, group-policy

I am working with OpenLDAP and client browser as Apache directory Studio.
I did whatever required for enforcing ppolicies to the openLDAP users still I think its missing something and someware.
This is my ppolicy.ldif

```
       dn: dc=maxcrc,dc=com
       objectClass: top
       objectClass: domain
       dc: maxcrc

        dn: ou=People,dc=maxcrc,dc=com
       objectClass: organizationalUnit
       objectClass: top
       ou: People
       description: Container for user entries



      dn: ou=policies,dc=maxcrc,dc=com
      objectClass: top
      objectClass: organizationalUnit
      ou: policies

      dn: cn=default,ou=policies,dc=maxcrc,dc=com
      objectClass: pwdPolicy
      objectClass: top
      objectClass: device
      cn: default
      pwdAttribute: userPassword
      pwdAllowUserChange: TRUE
      pwdCheckQuality: 1
      pwdExpireWarning: 86400
      pwdInHistory: 6
      pwdLockout: TRUE
      pwdLockoutDuration: 1920
      pwdMaxAge: 172800
      pwdMaxFailure: 4
      pwdMinLength: 6
      pwdSafeModify: FALSE

      dn: uid=jery,dc=maxcrc,dc=com
      objectClass: pwdPolicy
      objectClass: posixAccount
      objectClass: top
      objectClass: account
      cn: maxcrc jery
      gidNumber: 1011
      homeDirectory: /home/jery
        pwdAttribute: userPassword
      uid: jery
    uidNumber: 1011
    pwdPolicySubentry:cn=strong,ou=policies,dc=maxcrc,dc=com      



      dn: cn=strong,ou=policies,dc=maxcrc,dc=com
     objectClass: device
     objectClass: top
      objectClass: pwdPolicy
      cn: strong
      pwdAttribute: userPassword
      pwdMaxAge: 1296000
     pwdMinLength: 4
```

still it allows to add userPassword from apache directory studio with more than 4 character.can anyone tell me why is it so?  Thanks in advance .

below is my sldap.config file

```
    # BDB Backend configuration file
    # See slapd.conf(5) for details on configuration options.
    # This file should NOT be world readable.
     ucdata-path    ./ucdata
     include        ./schema/core.schema
      include       ./schema/cosine.schema
     include        ./schema/nis.schema
      include       ./schema/inetorgperson.schema
       include      ./schema/openldap.schema
          include       ./schema/dyngroup.schema
          include       ./schema/ppolicy.schema

            moduleload      ppolicy.la
            moduleload      syncprov.la
            moduleload back_bdb.la
            moduleload back_ldap.la
             pidfile        ./run/slapd.pid
                argsfile    ./run/slapd.args
                   # Enable TLS if port is defined for ldaps


             TLSVerifyClient never
               TLSCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:-SSLv2
            TLSCertificateFile ./secure/certs/server.pem
            TLSCertificateKeyFile ./secure/certs/server.pem
            TLSCACertificateFile ./secure/certs/server.pem

               #######################################################################
           # bdb database definitions
           #######################################################################
             database   monitor

            database    bdb
            suffix      "dc=maxcrc,dc=com"

             # invokes password policies for this DIT only
             overlay    ppolicy

             # Default ppolicy
                ppolicy_default "cn=strong,ou=policies,dc=maxcrc,dc=com"

            # Some ppolicy directives

             ppolicy_use_lockout
                ppolicy_hash_cleartext


           # ACL1


       #access to attrs=userPassword
       #      by self       write
       #    by anonymous  auth
        #   by group.exact="cn=Manager,dc=maxcrc,dc=com"
        #                 write
       #   by *          none
       # ACL3
  #access to *
     #    by self       write
       #   by group.exact="cn=Manager,dc=maxcrc,dc=com"
         #                write
       #   by users      read
     #   by *          none





          rootdn        "cn=Manager,dc=maxcrc,dc=com"
        # Cleartext passwords, especially for the rootdn, should
         # be avoid.  See slappasswd(8) and slapd.conf(5) for details.
          # Use of strong authentication encouraged.
            rootpw    secret



     # The database directory MUST exist prior to running slapd AND
       # should only be accessible by the slapd and slap tools.
       # Mode 700 recommended.
           directory ./data
          dirtyread
           searchstack 20
       # Indices to maintain
           index mail pres,eq
          index objectclass pres
       index default eq,sub
      index sn eq,sub,subinitial
       index telephonenumber
      index cn
```

Comment: Off topic for SO. Have you defined the password policy stuff in `slapd.conf?`

Comment: yes so far I know 'include./schema/ppolicy.schema''moduleload      ppolicy.la''overlay  ppolicy''ppolicy_default "cn=default,ou=policies,dc=maxcrc,dc=com"'

Comment: When you say 'more than 4 character[s]' do you mean 'less than six'?

Comment: No I mean that ,for default ppolicy Min length should be 6 but I defined pwdPolicySubentry:cn=strong,ou=policies,dc=maxcrc,dc=com   so min length is 4 here. but it allows me to enter 1 charecter password also .It shoud not allow password less than 4 charecter for this policy cn=strong,ou=policies,dc=maxcrc,dc=com.

Comment: Here I am not using default ppolicy  dn: cn=default,ou=policies,dc=maxcrc,dc=com  I am using policy dn:cn=strong,ou=policies,dc=maxcrc,dc=com.

Comment: So when you say it allows 'more than 4' you really mean 'less than 4'?

Comment: It should never allow me to enter password less than 4 charecters for a user having pwdPolicySubentry:cn=strong,ou=policies,dc=maxcrc. but it is allowing me to enter the password less than 4 charecter. am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

The password policy overlay requires you not to carry out the operation as the rootDN. You should use an admin login defined in the DIT that has the appropriate permissions.

Comment: could you please provide me a link to refer for extended password modify operation to understand.